# Entity Framework 6 one-to-many with a reference to last record

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have two entities in my model, and they have a one to many relationship like this

```
public class Analysis : Entity
{
    public virtual IList<Process> Processes{ get; set; }
}
public class Process: Entity
{
     public virtual Analysis Analysis { get; set; }
}
```

This works fine, but to optimize my code and limit my model I'd like to expose only the last process in my Analysis, like this:

```
 public class Analysis : Entity
{
    public virtual Process Process { get; set; }
}
public class Process: Entity
{
     public virtual Analysis Analysis { get; set; }
}
```

But I don't want the Process property to be a column in my Analysis table, instead of this, I want to load this property with the last Process for this Analysis Id.

How do I implement this in the ModelBuider?

Comment: Just add property to `Analysis` class: `public Process LastProcess { get { return Processes.Last(); } }` with `[NotMapped]` attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I inspired in  Slava Utesinov idea and created a new idea for more performance, his idea would load all processes in the analysis.

first i created a sql function to return the last process

```
    CREATE FUNCTION UDFGetProcess(   @Id int )   RETURNS int AS
    BEGIN
        declare @rint
        select top 1 @r = id from Process p where p.analysis_id = @id order by CreationDate desc
        return @r
    END
```

then I changed the class like this

```
public class Analysis : Entity
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]
    public virtual Process Process { get; set; }
}
```

and changed the modelcontext

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Process>().HasRequired(x => x.Analysis).WithMany().WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

Added the migration and changed the creation of the field to this

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.Analisys ADD Process_Id AS dbo.UDFGetProcess(id)
```

this way the return is what I intended and the performance is the same.